# Windows 10 Preview and Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-10-preview

I want to install Windows 10 Preview, and want to know if Visual Studio works on it. I assume that libraries would work if that happens, but I want to be sure if it works.

Comment: That answer is 4 months old, though. What's the curent situation?

Comment: try the VS2015 CTP

Comment: I've had no issue running 2013 on it, though it was installed before the upgrade to 10.

Comment: Interesting. I'd like a clean install, though. Better to clear the registry and everything that I don't need anymore, especially because win10 is so different than 7.